# Default App for opening videos is SMPlayer, then why videos are being opened in Movie Player?

Tags: default-programs

I prefer smplayer over the movie-player to view videos on my 12.04.1. So I have set the default application for opening the videos as 'smplayer' under `"Default Applications>>Video"` .

But the change in the settings doesn't seem to help as searching for the video from unity plays it in Movie Player (previous default for video files).

Is there any step that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Ubuntu 12.04 currently does not follow the global defaults set under **System Settings->Details->Default applications**.

What you can do is go to that video's location in the File Manager, right click, then select **Properties**, go to the **Open with** tab, select the application you want (in your case that would be SMPlayer), the click **Set as default**.

Note that you will have to do this for every extension, if you do this for a .flv file, all .flv files will open in SMPlayer, same for .mp4, .wmv, and others.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution would be to replace the bindings in the `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` for all the lines that start with "video".

The lines are of the form video/*format* = *application*.desktop. To open a 3gpp video with  vlc, the line:

```
video/3gpp = totem.desktop --> video/3gpp=vlc.desktop.
```

Comment: I assume you mean defaults.list right? I upvoted your answer because usually this is what _should_ happen. However, Ubuntu, especially the newer versions (12.04 and 12.10) does not seem to respect those. E.g. Totem is the default media player for all video files in my defaults.list, however VLC opens my video files by default.

Comment: yes.. my bad.. corrected that.. thanks for pointing it out.